# resize function and change css value of my class (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to write a script that will change one css but only if the condition in if is true. I do not understand why my script just does not work (even if I paste it in the browser console)

```
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", function () {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 767px)').matches && window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1259px)').matches) {
        $('.filter--facet-container').each(function () {
            if ($(this).children().length >= 3 && $(this).children().length <= 4) {
                $(".listing--actions.filter--container-additional").css("height", "125px");
            }
        })
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

`document` has no `load` event, notice nothing happens:

```js
$(document).load(function() {
  console.log("Ran");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You may have meant `$(window).load(function(){ ... })`:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  console.log("Ran");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but beware that that event happens **very** late in the page load cycle, after all resources (including all images) have been loaded.

To run your code when the DOM is complete but before the `load` event, just put your code in a `script` tag at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag (or use jQuery's `$(function() { })` "DOM ready" feature, though there's no real need for it).

---

A couple of other notes:

1. [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is obsolete and deprecated. With modern jQuery (and hopefully you're using a modern version), use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
2. `matchMedia` returns an object with events for when the result of the rule changes, so there's no need to use `resize`.
3. `matchMedia` allows "and", no need for two separate checks.

Instead, for just a reactive check:

```
<script>
matchMedia("(max-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1259px)").addListener(function(e) {
    if (e.matches) {
        // Your .filter--facet-container logic here
    }
});
</body>
</html>
```

or for an initial proactive check and then reactive checks afterward (probably what you want):

```
<script>
(function() { // Avoid creating globals
    var matcher = matchMedia("(max-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1259px)");
    function facetContainerLogic() {
        // Your .filter--facet-container logic here
    }
    // Proactive initial check
    if (matcher.matches) {
        facetContainerLogic();
    }
    // Get notifications when it changes
    matcher.addListener(function(e) {
        if (e.matches) {
            facetContainerLogic();
        }
    });
})();
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wanted to paste this script in console, but its is still not working

Comment: @JsStorm2 - It **does** work. It fires an event when the condition changes. If you want an initial proactive check, you'd do that separately. I've updated to show that. See also [MDN's coverage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries) of JavaScript media queries.